# SQLite ordering by score not working

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database which is taking in users and their score from a quiz. I also have this database table to order by score in descending order. The score they gain from each correct answer is + 100 so there are 10 questions at a maximum of 1000.

My problem is that it seems to be taking 1000 as 100 and putting it lower than a score of 200. The sql query I am using for this is:

```
SELECT rankId, firstName, lastName, score FROM leader ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it seems to be taking 1000 as 100

That happens when you sort on a text column. You get alphabetic ordering that way.

Alter your table to make the score column numeric (or pad the contents with leading zeros to a fixed width).